# UINavigation inconsistent behavior when title is long with UIWebView

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm experiencing weird behavior of UINavigation. Ideal behavior is when title is too long, back button text should be hide and shows only icon.
 [image]

Sometimes it worked as I expected, sometimes it didn't and back button text was overlapped by title text as shown below.
[image]

Back button is default and no custom stuffs added on it. Any idea why this is happening?

Update:

Here's some source code,

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {
   ....
        self.navigationItem.title = [self getDocumentTitle];
   ....

}
```

and getDocumentTitle just return NSString. I still do not think any third-party or custom view title was used here.

Comment: And for the `title`, is it a custom `UIView`?

Comment: No, its default title I believe

Comment: A couple of other things that are strange here: The title or titleView is usually adjusted to the right (off-center) to make room before the Back button is truncated. That doesn't seem to be the case here. Also, I believe the titleView will by default be constrained to a region that will leave the Back button shown. Are you certain that you're not using any third party libraries or custom views that could be affecting this?

Comment: I suspected it as Jacky mentioned, but I do not see any third party nor custom view but just setting self.navigationItem.title to some text

Comment: I just did a quick test with a navigation controller showing a web view, and setting the title to varying lengths all worked correctly. Is your -getDocumentTitle method truncating the title ahead of time? It seems that the Back button is usually dropped before the title is shortened with ellipses.

Comment: It seems like some timing issue. I just tested with static string and set title with it when `webViewDidFinishLoad:` was called on same site. Sometimes it properly dropped, sometimes not

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said is strange, if it's by default (iOS 7 bug?). Experiment adding a custom view like this:

```
UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,100.0f,40.0f)];
titleLabel.text = @"My title"
titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[titleLabel setMinimumFontSize:5];
titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
[titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:WHSTitleFont size:17.0f]];
[titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
```